# Cleanup old refs in Ruby Version Manager (RVM)

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2

I need to free disk space on my local machine, which is almost allocated into my Ruby Version Manager (RVM) dir.

Now, it seems I got just one ruby version ( 1.9.2p136 ) :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [i686-linux]
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$ 

lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$ rvm list
rvm rubies
=> ruby-1.9.2-p136 [ i386 ] 
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$

lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$ which ruby
/home/lsoave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$
```

but my RVM dir, have many others unrelated dirs/versions :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$ ls -la ~/.rvm/gems
total 72
drwxr-xr-x 18 lsoave lsoave 4096 2011-05-21 15:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 lsoave lsoave 4096 2011-02-10 22:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 lsoave lsoave 4096 2010-08-29 19:50 cache
drwxr-xr-x  2 lsoave lsoave 4096 2010-08-31 21:50 jruby-1.3.7
drwxr-xr-x  2 lsoave lsoave 4096 2010-08-31 21:50 jruby-1.3.8
drwxr-xr-x  2 lsoave lsoave 4096 2011-05-21 15:44 ree-1.8.7-2010.02
drwxr-xr-x  8 lsoave lsoave 4096 2010-09-08 11:25 ruby-1.8.7-p302
drwxr-xr-x  7 lsoave lsoave 4096 2010-08-29 22:00 ruby-1.8.7-p302@global
drwxr-xr-x  7 lsoave lsoave 4096 2010-08-29 22:24 ruby-1.9.2-head
drwxr-xr-x  7 lsoave lsoave 4096 2010-08-29 22:24 ruby-1.9.2-head@global
drwxr-xr-x  8 lsoave lsoave 4096 2010-08-31 23:47 ruby-1.9.2-p0
drwxr-xr-x  7 lsoave lsoave 4096 2010-08-29 19:50 ruby-1.9.2-p0@global
drwxr-xr-x  8 lsoave lsoave 4096 2011-02-10 19:44 ruby-1.9.2-p136
drwxr-xr-x  7 lsoave lsoave 4096 2011-02-10 19:23 ruby-1.9.2-p136@global
drwxr-xr-x  7 lsoave lsoave 4096 2011-04-08 21:21 ruby-1.9.2-p136@greendog
drwxr-xr-x  7 lsoave lsoave 4096 2011-04-09 00:57 ruby-1.9.2-p136@greendog2
drwxr-xr-x  7 lsoave lsoave 4096 2011-02-15 00:09 ruby-1.9.2-p136@greendog99
drwxr-xr-x  2 lsoave lsoave 4096 2011-02-10 19:04 system
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$
```

is it save to remove all dirs remaining with just "ruby-1.9.2-p136" and "ruby-1.9.2-p136@global" dirs (ruby-1.9.2-p136@greendog* are old and "rvm system" return nothing) ? Will I use "rm" command, or are there RVM embodied commands to cleanup a better way ? Is it possible cleanup the cache dir ?

Thanks in advance.
luca

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suppose `rvm cleanup` could do the trick.

Other than that I don't see any reason that deleting the actual gem directories inside RVM if they aren't associated with RVM any more.

If the matching entry doesn't exist in `environments` then it is safe to delete the accompanying gem dir. As nothing else points to it that RVM would be able to use.

Comment: If the matching entry doesn't exist in `environments` then it is safe to delete the accompanying gem dir. As nothing else points to it that RVM would be able to use.

Comment: I did `rvm cleanup all` in order to delete an unused ruby version, 1.9.3-p362. It removed almost everything, but left directories `.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p362` and `.rvm/patchsets/ruby/1.9.3/p362`. Actually, the `.rvm/patches/ruby/` and `.rvm/patchsets/ruby/` directories still contain subdirectories for all Ruby versions ever installed on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

... it turn out that some of the previous, not used refs, were just gemsets:

```
rvm gemset list
lsoave@ubuntu:~$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p136 (found in /home/lsoave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136)
global
greendog
greendog2
greendog99

lsoave@ubuntu:~$
```

which I removed like following:

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~$ rvm gemset delete greendog99
Are you SURE you wish to remove the entire gemset directory 'greendog99' (/home/lsoave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@greendog99)?
(anything other than 'yes' will cancel) > yes
lsoave@ubuntu:~$ rvm gemset delete greendog2
Are you SURE you wish to remove the entire gemset directory 'greendog2' (/home/lsoave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@greendog2)?
(anything other than 'yes' will cancel) > yes
lsoave@ubuntu:~$ rvm gemset delete greendog
Are you SURE you wish to remove the entire gemset directory 'greendog' (/home/lsoave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@greendog)?
(anything other than 'yes' will cancel) > yes
lsoave@ubuntu:~$
```

than I made a backup of one of the old 'lib' ( just in case ... ):

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/.rvm/gems$ tar zcvf ruby-1.8.7-p302.gz ./ruby-1.8.7-p302
```

and removed the relative directory as a previous comment talk, with stuartc:

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/.rvm/gems$ rm -rf ./ruby-1.8.7-p302
```

now back to work.

I'll wait a couple of days, looking for everything is right ...

Comment: Everything all right, I can now remove the old ruby-1.8.7-p302.gz. Thanks stuartc